# Push Objects into an array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array with objects, but the array is not filling properly. The last value is set in all positions of the array. Here's the code:

```js
var matrixprice = 5;
var qualifiedDate = '2019-10-01';

var today = new Date();
var qDate = new Date(qualifiedDate);
var nextDay = qDate;
var myObject = new Object();

var myArray = [];

var dailybonus = matrixprice * 0.03;

var full_bonus = matrixprice * 2;

var i = 0;

while (i <= full_bonus) {

  nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
  i += dailybonus;

  myObject.title = '$' + i;
  myObject.start = nextDay;

  myArray.push(myObject);
}


var myString = JSON.stringify(myArray);

console.log(myString);
```

The array Im getting is filled with only 1 value in all positions it looks like this:

```
[{"title":"$100.5","start":"2020-01-03T18:50:23.000Z"},           {"title":"$100.5","start":"2020-01-03T18:50:23.000Z"},{"title":"$100.5","start":"2020-01-03T18:50:23.000Z"},{"title":"$100.5","start":"2020-01-03T18:50:23.000Z"},{"title":"$100.5","start":"2020-01-03T18:50:23.000Z"},{"title":"$100.5","start":"2020-01-03T18:50:23.000Z"}]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're not reassigning myObject.  You're modifying and pushing the same object over and over.

Comment: how can I reassing myObject? yes its pushing the same object all the time..how can I correct it?

Comment: You are putting just the whole object made from objects. You must loop through the object. But you have to choose what do you want to put in every item of the array.: an object, titles of the objects,date, price??

Comment: In your loop, before you set `title` and `start`, `myObject = {}` (or just `myObject = {title: ..., start: ...}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your while loop to push a new object:

```js
while(i <= full_bonus){
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate()+1); 
    i += dailybonus;

    myArray.push({title: '$'+i, start: new Date(nextDay)});
}
```

Here's the full, working example:

```js
var matrixprice = 5;
var qualifiedDate = '2019-10-01';

var today = new Date();
var qDate = new Date(qualifiedDate);
var nextDay = qDate;

var myArray = [];
var dailybonus = matrixprice * 0.03;
var full_bonus = matrixprice * 2;

var i = 0;

while(i <= full_bonus){
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate()+1); 
    i += dailybonus;

    myArray.push({title: '$'+i, start: new Date(nextDay)});
}

var myString = JSON.stringify(myArray);

console.log(myString);
```